# node GET request displays body

Tags: node.js, get

I have a redirect request which does a GET of the correct page. Here is the log:

```
{ request:
   { uri: 'https://xxxx:10635/html/create.html?showMessage=Created',
     method: 'GET',
     headers:
      { referer: 'https://xxxxx:10635/html/volume/create_submit.tml',
        host: 'xxxxx:10635' } } }
{ response:
   { headers:
      { 'content-type': 'text/html',
        'content-length': '76844' },
     statusCode: 200,
     body: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Str ../../common/termsConditions.html\', \'termsConditions\')">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>&nbsp;:&nbsp;<a class="footer_element" href="/html/sitemap.htm">Site Map</a>&nbsp;:&nbsp;<a class="footer_element" href=/index.html>Home</a>\n\t\t\t\t</span>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td colspan="3"><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t\t<td bgcolor="#cccccc"><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t\t<td><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td colspan="3"><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t\t<td valign="top">\n\t\t\t<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">\n\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t<td nowrap><span class="copyright">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;2016&nbsp;<a class="copyright" </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;All rights reserved.</span><br /></td>\n\t\t\t\t<td align="right" ><a target=_blank><img src="/html/images/header/f" alt="" border="0" /></a></td>\n\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t\t</table>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t\t<td><img src="/html/images/header/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t\t</table>\n</td></tr>\n</table> \n-->\n</body>\n</html>' } }
```

Comment: What is the difference between page body and the web-page?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to say, the response includes the body (as above) but the web-page is not displayed. A normal response to a GET does not show the body.

Comment: Your sample does not include full body `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Str ....` is not helpful, so I cannot see what it should display.

Comment: Interestingly I see the following 2 header options in the GET request block which I do not for a normal GET request. 'cache-control': 'max-age=0' and         origin: 'https://xxxx',

Comment: If you want someone to answer you need to include full version of `body: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Str ....` in question

Comment: The body is displaying the page-source of the very page I do a request GET for. I need to redirect to it and get the actual html to display on the screen.

Comment: Instead of entering full response in comment you better edit your question and paste it as code fragment or if it is too big use sites like https://jsfiddle.net/ and put reference in question